# Hyperlink in a div with jQuery.toggle Event

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a DIV element which has a jQuery.toggle Event. If I add a hyperlink as content of this div, a click on this hyperlink will fire the jQuery.toggle Event of the parent div. Is it possible to prevent this? The hyperlink should just open the weblink, and not fire the event.

Comment: Do not mark "solved" in the title. Accept the answer you went with (first posting it yourself, if you solved it yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with :

```
$("#linkInsideYourDiv").click(function(event)) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just call unbind on the $(this).parent when you are in the child toggle first

i.e.

```
$(this).parent().unbind("toggle");
```

Another thing you can do is call the avoid propogation method to avoid passing the toggle / click event etc back up the chain of bound listeners.

i.e.

```
$(this).click(function(e){
    // Do your click stuff

    // Prevent any further processing of the click event
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```